# WebSphere 9 Not Able to Start or Not Able to Start Applications

Tags: java-8, websphere, websphere-9

I have upgraded my WebSphere from 8.5 to 9. Now, when starting the Server, I'm getting these exceptions. My Projects were working perfect in the 8.5 and now, after upgrading to 9, I'm not even able to start the WebSphere Server. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
[8/20/19 13:41:48:418 EDT] 00000057 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                             java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SubviewTag
           at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:403)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.loadClass(WASAnnotationHelper.java:1004)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.collectClasses(WASAnnotationHelper.java:214)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.<init>(WASAnnotationHelper.java:165)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager.getAnnotationHelper(WASAnnotationHelperManager.java:66)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.handOffReferenceData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:440)
           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:413)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:229)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:567)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.preStart(DeployedModuleImpl.java:553)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.preStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:849)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1045)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:786)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2238)
           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5488)
           at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
           at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2243)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
           at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
           at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your application is using Sun JSF RI that was provided in WAS 8.x and which is removed in WAS 9.0.

I'd strongly recommend to use migration tools to scan your application to find migration issues:

- [Toolkit for binaries](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) - which allows to scan archives (jar,war,ear)
- [Migration toolkit for Eclipse](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit) - Eclipse plugin available via Marketplace

These tools will find issues that you need to address during migration.

For your case, I'd say that you would need to include JSF jars in your WEB-INF/lib or migrate to MyFaces which is provided JSF implementation in WAS 9.x